# Finicity API handshake from Javascript fails with 401 but works with Postman

Tags: angular, rest, http, cors, postman

I am using Finicity API, and on my preliminary tests worked fine with Postman, but fails with HTTP status 401 when used from Angular 5 application, below the relevant code of the API call.

```
this.token = '';
const authBody =
`<credentials><partnerId>${this.partnerId}</partnerId><partnerSecret>${this.partnerSecret}</partnerSecret></credentials>`;
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml').set('Accept', 'application/json').
  set('Finicity-App-Key', this.appKey);

const result = <Observable<boolean>>this.http.request('post', this.baseUrl + this.pathAuthentication,
   {body: authBody, headers: headers, observe: 'body'}).pipe(share());
result.subscribe( (data) => {
  if (data) {
    try {
      this.token = (<any>data).access.token;
      return of(true);
    } catch (e) {
      this.handleError(e);
      return of(false);
    }
  }
}, (error) => {
  this.handleError(error);
  return of(false);
});
```

This API https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v2/partners/authentication is supposed to return the token to use for the whole session, and works perfectly in Postman. See docs https://community.finicity.com/s/article/201704129-Step-1-Partner-Authentication

NOTE: I have also set up a dummy web server that dumps the whole request in text & hex and both Postman & Angular client are sending the same request.
Also CORS is configured properly in the web server serving the Angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that Finicity backend is not properly responding to preflight requests
(the following image shows the error in Chrome):

[image: Chrome error in preflight request]

On the other hand, the request works perfectly fine with both Postman & C# client (both of them don't make a preflight request obviously).